# Migrate magento 1 to Magento 2 : Data migration tool change column type

Tags: magento2, magento-1, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool

I'm trying to migrate from Magento 1.7.0.2 to Magento 2.3.1

For that I use the migration tool :https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/migration/migration-tool-install.html

All is working fine except a custom table.

[image]

I get this message for the col2 when I launch the import :

- Mismatch of data types. Destination document: my_table. Fields: col2

Is it possible to tell the migration script to ignore the column type in the database (since it change from varchar to text) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my issue while looking in the map.xsd file. In my map.xml file I have used :

```
<destination>
    <field_rules>
        <ignore>
            <datatype>my_table.col2</datatype>
        </ignore>
    </field_rules>
</destination>
```